# How do I use PHP libraries without composer?

Tags: php, libraries

This is a really noob question... How do I use PHP libraries downloaded from GitHub? I've never experienced using libraries (even with the use of Composer). Where do I put the library folder? Are there any other steps I need to take to make the library work?

I'm trying to use PHPSpreadsheet to read and write Excel files; in their GitHub documentation, it's only about using the library in code.

I've tried searching for ways on how to use libraries without the use of Composer but they were all really specific and didn't apply to my situation. There were answers about using libraries on a server and about using libraries on Wordpress.

I just need to use the library for my thesis which will just be on one PC, no servers or anything.

Comment: Just place your libraries in one folder, e.g: `libs`, then just add `require 'path/to/your/lib/lib_name.php';` at the beginning of your PHP code

Comment: Just create a directory put the library file there and then include it into your php file using require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A computer is a computer - PHP doesn't care whether it's a server or not.  Believe it or not, every answer you saw did, indeed apply to your situation.  PHP is a tool - a hammer - and you can use it to drive in nails or put dents in a fender with equal efficiency.

Put the library folder anywhere you like - literally

Then, at the top of every `.php` file that needs to use the library, simply add:

`require '../relative/path/to/library/file.php'`

or

`require '/absolute/path/to/library/file.php'`

It's that easy ... welcome to the wonderful world of code - where EVERY decision you make will come back to bite you on the a** ;)

Comment: Worked like a charm. I really like the explanation @Ragdata haha!
Many thanks!

Comment: require_once is better if you are possibly using it in many files that may also require each other. It means that it will be called only once.

Comment: This guy just needed a nudge in the right direction so that he could complete an assignment for college before he went on to live a life in which he would never touch or even think about PHP again.  The likelihood that his library was going to be called more than once is one thing I can guarantee NEVER crossed his mind, and in his particular use-case, the library being called multiple times wouldn't have registered a blip on the radar performance-wise ... this also happens to be true everywhere that isn't receiving millions of requests per day, which is the only time it matters a damn ...

Comment: @Ragdata: just beautiful -- I love when ppl take into consideration where such questions are coming from  However, it would be nice to give a general answer to the audience that gets here from e.g. Google as well, so including stuff like using `require_once` instead can be useful for future visitors :)